# how can i send data to server and instant update listview from json in same fragment

Tags: android, json, listview, fragment, android-volley

How can I send data to a server and update a listview from that server with the data I sent? Note that data sending process and listview are in same fragment.

Here is my code. It works, but when I send data and open same activity it wasn't updated and university name and group name don't show or are null,but when go to other activity and back to it, the listview is updated!

```
public class GroupWallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView groupProPic;
    TextView groupName;
    TextView varsity;

    String userIdString;
    public String groupIdString;
    String groupNameString;
    String universityNameString;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_wall);

        groupName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.groupNameTV);
        varsity= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.varsityTV);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }
        groupNameString=getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupName");
        universityNameString=getIntent().getStringExtra("UniversityName");
        groupName.setText(groupNameString);
        varsity.setText(universityNameString);


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        groupIdString=getIntent().getStringExtra("GroupId");
        userIdString=getIntent().getStringExtra("UserId");

        Bundle fragmentOneBundle = new Bundle();
        fragmentOneBundle.putString("group_id", groupIdString);
        fragmentOneBundle.putString("userId",userIdString);
        fragmentOneBundle.putString("groupName",groupNameString);
        fragmentOneBundle.putString("universityName",universityNameString);
        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        fragmentOne.setArguments(fragmentOneBundle);




        Bundle fragmentTwoBundle=new Bundle();
        fragmentTwoBundle.putString("group_id", groupIdString);
        fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
        fragmentTwo.setArguments(fragmentTwoBundle);

        adapter.addFragment(fragmentOne, "Post");
        adapter.addFragment(fragmentTwo, "Member");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);
        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(GroupWallActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.appbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.logout) {

            logoutUser();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

FRAGMENT

```
    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = FragmentOne.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    Button postButton;
    EditText postText;
    ListView postListView;


    private String groupIdString;
    private String userIdString;
    private String postBody;
    private String groupNameString;
    private String universityNameString;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    ArrayList<PostModel> postList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);



        postButton= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.postBtn);
        postText= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.postTextET);
        postListView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.postListLV);

        groupIdString =getArguments().getString("group_id");
        userIdString =getArguments().getString("userId");
        groupNameString=getArguments().getString("groupName");
        universityNameString=getArguments().getString("universityName");


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        postList=db.getPostFromPostTable(groupIdString );
        if(postList.size()!=0 && postList.size()>0) {


            final CustomAdapterPost customAdapterPost = new CustomAdapterPost(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, postList);
            postListView.setAdapter(customAdapterPost);
        }

        postButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        postBody=postText.getText().toString().trim();
       postAnnouncement(userIdString,groupIdString,postBody);


    }


    private void postAnnouncement(final String userId,final String groupId,final String postBody) {


        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        progressDialog.setMessage("Posting ...");

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_POST, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Post Response: " + response.toString());

                try {


                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite


                        JSONArray groupArray = jObj.optJSONArray("mypost");

                        for(int i=0; i < groupArray.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject post = groupArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String postUniqueId = post.getString("post_unique_id");
                            String userUniqueId = post.getString("user_unique_id");
                            String groupUniqueId= post.getString("group_unique_id");
                            String userName = post.getString("user_name");
                            String postBody = post.getString("post_body");
                            String createdAt = post.getString("created_at");

                            // Inserting row in  table
                            db.addPostToPostTable(postUniqueId, userUniqueId, groupUniqueId, userName, postBody, createdAt);

                        }

                        // Launch GroupWall activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), GroupWallActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("UserId",userIdString);
                        intent.putExtra("GroupId",groupIdString);
                        intent.putExtra("GroupName",groupNameString);
                        intent.putExtra("UniversityName",universityNameString);
                        startActivity(intent);




                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Post Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put("user_unique_id", userId);
                params.put("group_unique_id", groupId);
                params.put("post_body", postBody);


                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(strReq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifydatasetchanged() on your adapter.